# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in line XX

Tags: php, mysqli

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in line 88
>
> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in line 91

I marked the lines down below, I tried to change the query just in case but it doesn't seem to be working. I looked it up and I just couldn't find a solution. I also noticed all these answers were downvoted but I am a newbie in PHP, so I don't really know what to look for. I suppose that's something simple but I'm just not looking at the right place. Why is that happening? And how can I fix it?

```
$number = rand(pow(10, 11-1), pow(10, 11)-1);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email= ? OR number= ? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $number);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$user = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

function uniqueNum() {
    global $number;
    $number = rand(pow(10, 11-1), pow(10, 11)-1);
    if ($user['number'] === $number) {
        uniqueNum();
    }
}

if ($user) {
    if ($user['email'] === $email) { // Line 88
        array_push($errors, "E-Mail already exists");
    }
    if ($user['number'] === $number) { // Line 91
        uniqueNum();
    }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated! I'm 15 and I'm just learning how to do registration forms, so I would happily listen to some extra advice!

Comment: I assume `// Line 81` means `// Line 88` ?

Comment: Oh my, excuse me! Yes, Line 81 is 88! I'll try to fix that.

Comment: You should also be getting a `$user` out of scope error from within the function

Comment: Would `global $user;` fix the issue?

Comment: the function mysqli_stmt_fetch returns a boolean value, not the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing PDO with mysqli. Mysqli is much more complicated and `mysqli_stmt_fetch` does not actually return any values. You can make this much simpler if you use `get_result` and OOP-style. You can then use for example, `fetch_assoc()` to get a single row out of the result object.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email= ? OR number= ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $number);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

if($user) {
    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
        array_push($errors, "E-Mail already exists");
    }
    if ($user['number'] === $number) {
        uniqueNum();
    }
}
```